# Отрисовка картинок в canvas

Tags: javascript, функции, canvas

Я хочу сделать,чтобы функцию draw можно было бы применять много раз с разными картинками, но у меня почему-то не выходит. Может это особенности canvas. Можно ли что-нибудь с этим сделать?

```js
    let canvas = document.getElementById('field');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let cat = new Image();
    let dog = new Image();
    cat.src = 'http://mignews.com/aimages/04_16/150416_221507_60345_2.jpg';
    dog.src = 'http://petsblog.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/shcenochek-600x330.jpg';
    function draw(img) {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    draw(cat);
    draw(dog);
```

```html
<canvas id="field" width="900" height="400">hi</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно дождаться загрузки картинки, установив обработчик `onload`

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('field');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let cat = new Image();
let dog = new Image();
cat.src = 'https://picsum.photos/id/102/300/200';
dog.src = 'https://picsum.photos/id/103/300/200';
cat.onload = () => ctx.drawImage(cat, 0, 0, cat.width, cat.height);
dog.onload = () => ctx.drawImage(dog, 300, 0, dog.width, dog.height);
```

```html
<canvas id="field" width="600" height="175"></canvas>
```