# JS не рисуется изображение на canvas

Tags: javascript, html

Суть проблемы в том, что не рисуется ничего в canvas. В атрибут функции image1 передаю src и в консоли получаю "вход: (тут base64 изображения входного)", а на втором вызове консоли "выход: (тут base64 прозрачного изображения)". Т.е. на canvas ничего не рисуется.

```
function finalGlue(image1){

var img1 = new Image();

console.log("вход: " + image1);
var canv = document.createElement('canvas'),
c = canv.getContext("2d");

img1.src = image1;
c.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

console.log("выход: " + c.canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
$("#preview_img").attr("src", c.canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));

}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1010087/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-canvas/1010098#1010098

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо, частично решило вопрос, но всплыла новая проблема. Может вы знаете, что может быть не так? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1010529/js-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%b2-canvas