# JS Не рисуются картинки большого разрешеня в canvas

Tags: javascript

Когда пытаюсь нарисовать в canvas изображение большее, чем 500x500, то получаю в итоге белый прямоугольник. Если пытаюсь нарисовать меньшее, чем 500x500, то все работает.

```
function finalGlue(image1){ 

var img1 = new Image();

img1.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

console.log("вход: " + image1);

var canv = document.createElement('canvas'),
c = canv.getContext("2d");


   img1.src = image1;
   img1.onload = function() {

    console.log("height: " + img1.height + ", width: " + img1.width);
    c.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

    console.log("выход: " + c.canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
    $("#preview_img").attr("src", c.canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
};


    }
```

Comment: лучше бы конечно пример, который не работает не работал бы в сниппете, я полагаю надо устанавливать размер канвы

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, действительно, добавил          canv.width=img1.width;
         canv.height=img1.height;

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: нет проблем, обращайтесь